# How can I check for repeated strings with check-tail plugin in Sensu?

Tags: ruby, regex, runtime-error, sensu

I am using sensu and the [check-tail.rb](https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-filesystem-checks/blob/master/bin/check-tail.rb) plugin to alert if any errors appear in my app logs. The problem is that I want the check to be successful if it finds 3 or more error messages.

The solution that I came up with is using a regex like:

```
\^.*"status":503,.*$.*^.*"status":503,.*$.*^.*"status":503,.*$\im
```

But it seems to not work because of the match function: instead of passing the variable as a ruby regex it passes it as a string (this can be seen [here](https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-filesystem-checks/blob/master/bin/check-tail.rb#L68)).

Comment: What if you remove the backslashes and use `(?im)^.*"status":503,.*$.*^.*"status":503,.*$.*^.*"status":503,.*$`?

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Please answer my question and I will approve it.

Comment: I added an answer, please check if the ``\`` should be doubled (if you use double quoted string literal, they must be doubled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the pattern as a string literal, not as a Regexp object.

Thus, you need to remove the regex delimiters and change the modifiers to their inline option variants, that is, prepend the pattern with `(?im)`.

```
(?im)\A.*"status":503,.*$.*^.*"status":503,.*$.*^.*"status":5‌​03,.*\z
```

Note that to match the start of string in Ruby, you need to use `\A` and to match the end of string, you need to use `\z` anchors.

Comment: If you use a double quoted string literal, `\A` and `\z` must be doubled escaped.